# Querying with an arbitrary boolean expression on a join table

Tags: sql, database, join, sqlite

I am trying to model a many-to-many relationship between the `item` and `tag` tables. I have a join table `tagitemjoin` to accomplish that. For example:

```
 id | tag_id | item_id
-----------------------
  1 |    1   |    1
  2 |    2   |    1
  3 |    2   |    2
  4 |    3   |    1
  5 |    3   |    2
  6 |    3   |    3
  7 |    4   |    2
  8 |    4   |    3
  9 |    5   |    3
```

which represents the following connections

```
       | item: 1 | item: 2 | item: 3
-------------------------------------
tag: 1 |    *    |         |
tag: 2 |    *    |    *    |
tag: 3 |    *    |    *    |    *
tag: 4 |         |    *    |    *
tag: 5 |         |         |    *
```

I wish to query for a list of `item`s based on arbitrary boolean expressions involving `tag`s for example:

```
tag1 OR ((NOT tag2) AND tag3)
```

Since I need to implement the 3 basic operators, I was able to implement `OR` as follows:

```
SELECT i.* FROM item i
           INNER JOIN tagitemjoin j
           ON (j.item_id = i.id)
           WHERE (j.tag_id = 3) OR (j.tag_id = 4) GROUP BY i.id
```

and I'm sure I can also implement the `NOT` and `AND` operator using `COUNT` in some way. However ...

How do I expand this definition to be able to handle arbitrary boolean expressions? Is this something that is possible using this method of a join table?

If not, I will probably use a NoSQL approach of storing the `tag`s as a set in the `item`s dictionaries themselves since that method is more straight-forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing the join with subqueries allows writing the boolean expression in a more natural way:

```
WITH tag1 AS (SELECT item_id FROM tagitemjoin WHERE tag_id = 1),
     tag2 AS (SELECT item_id FROM tagitemjoin WHERE tag_id = 2),
     tag3 AS (SELECT item_id FROM tagitemjoin WHERE tag_id = 3)
SELECT * FROM item
WHERE id IN tag1 OR (id NOT IN tag2 AND id IN tag3);
```

Answer (score 1):

I like `group by` and `having` for this.  For instance, for tags 3 or 4:

```
select tij.item_id
from tagitemjoin tij
group by tij.item_id
having sum(case when tij.tag_id = 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or
       sum(case when tij.tag_id = 4 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

The `sum(case . . . )` counts the number of items the tag appears.  The condition then uses `> 0` to say that the tag exists; `= 0` would be used to specify that the tag does not exist.

This frame is quite generalizable.  It can be used for any boolean combination of tags.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for the help. Now I just have to try to create a template for constructing these.

Comment: @sshashank124 . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: I just preferred the other answer's approach since it's more modular and readable